# Trying To Open Up A New Screen/Activity In Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to switch to a new screen when the user clicks on one of the options. This code is nested in the main activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.about_settings:
                Log.d("tcc", "This is getting to the about fragment");
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpFragment.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.help_settings:
                Log.d("tcc", "This is getting to the help fragment");
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsFragment.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I am then trying to get it to switch to one of the fragments that I have created. When I do this though I am getting an error:

```
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{info.hccis.bookingapplication/info.hccis.bookingapplication.SettingsFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: info.hccis.bookingapplication.SettingsFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Comment: you cannot open a  fragment via intent, fragment is different then activity, you are passing fragment class

Comment: Learn How to Work with Fragment and Fundas of Fragment Manager and Fragment Transaction !!! ;(

Comment: You need to use FragmentManager if you want to work with fragment and not with the Intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do Fragment Transactions not `startActivity` :

```
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     switch (item.getItemId()) {

         case R.id.about_settings:
             Log.d("tcc", "This is getting to the about fragment");
             FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HelpFragment());
             fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); // to provided navigation when back is clicked
             fragmentTransaction.commit();
             return true;

         case R.id.help_settings:
             Log.d("tcc", "This is getting to the help fragment");

             FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment());
             fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); // to provided navigation when back is clicked
             fragmentTransaction.commit();
             return true;

         default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
 }
```

> And define a fragment coinainer/which will be replaced by your
>   fragments: in your Activity's View:

```
 <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
```